# Как изменить изображение в панораме google?

Tags: google-maps-api, google-maps

С помощью google maps api есть возможность отображать панорамы на своем сайте. Google строит панораму из набора тайлов (маленьких изображений). Есть ли возможность показывать измененный (свой собственный) тайл вместо "родного" тайла панорамы google (то есть необходимо подменить один из тайлов на свой)? Если да, то как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно имеется ввиду **[Custom Street View panorama tiles](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-custom-tiles)**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Custom Street View panorama tiles</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #street-view {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="street-view"></div>
    <script>

var panorama;

// StreetViewPanoramaData of a panorama just outside the Google Sydney office.
var outsideGoogle;

// StreetViewPanoramaData for a custom panorama: the Google Sydney reception.
function getReceptionPanoramaData() {
  return {
    location: {
      pano: 'reception',  // The ID for this custom panorama.
      description: 'Google Sydney - Reception',
      latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.86684, 151.19583)
    },
    links: [{
      heading: 195,
      description: 'Exit',
      pano: outsideGoogle.location.pano
    }],
    copyright: 'Imagery (c) 2010 Google',
    tiles: {
      tileSize: new google.maps.Size(1024, 512),
      worldSize: new google.maps.Size(2048, 1024),
      centerHeading: 105,
      getTileUrl: function(pano, zoom, tileX, tileY) {
        return 'images/' +
            'panoReception1024-' + zoom + '-' + tileX + '-' + tileY + '.jpg';
      }
    }
  };
}

function initPanorama() {
  panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
      document.getElementById('street-view'),
      {
        pano: outsideGoogle.location.pano,
        // Register a provider for our custom panorama.
        panoProvider: function(pano) {
          if (pano === 'reception') {
            return getReceptionPanoramaData();
          }
        }
      });

  // Add a link to our custom panorama from outside the Google Sydney office.
  panorama.addListener('links_changed', function() {
    if (panorama.getPano() === outsideGoogle.location.pano) {
      panorama.getLinks().push({
        description: 'Google Sydney',
        heading: 25,
        pano: 'reception'
      });
    }
  });
}

function initialize() {
  // Use the Street View service to find a pano ID on Pirrama Rd, outside the
  // Google office.
  var streetviewService = new google.maps.StreetViewService;
  streetviewService.getPanorama(
      {location: {lat: -33.867386, lng: 151.195767}},
      function(result, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
          outsideGoogle = result;
          initPanorama();
        }
      });
}

    </script>
    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initialize">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Применить вашу панораму вы можете с изменеием значений  {location: {lat: -33.867386, lng: 151.195767}} на ваши данные. С **[этим инструментом](http://www.latlong.net/)** вы можете получить эти данные.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но нет. Данный код добавляет свою собственную панораму, а не изменяет часть панорамы google.

Comment: Я изменил мой ответ и ввёл дополнительную информацию.